# How to use ternary operator in react table accessory

Tags: reactjs, accessor

My accessor value is 1 or 0 I want change it ***Active*** or ***inActive*** How  I do this?

```
{
    Header: 'isActive',
    accessor: 'isActive'
}
```

Comment: accessor is not what you said in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This would return Active if your **attributeName** is **1** and vice-versa

```
{
    Header: 'isActive',
    id: "isActive",
    accessor: (row) => row.attributeName? 'Active' : 'isActive'
}
```

Comment: it return isActive when my attribute name is 1

Comment: but Thank you I find answer

Comment: {
            Header: 'isActive',
            id: "isActive",
            accessor: d => d.isActive == 1 ? 'Active' : 'inactive'
        } this work